# How do we say when the value of the variable is placed where the variable is? What's the name of this?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, language-agnostic

For homework I'm writing  a report and don't know what this is called: when the value of the variable is substituted into the statment.

**Simple example:**

var weekDay = Thursday
print "Today is "+ Weekday

In words I want to say 'print "Today is "+Weekday is `_____` to "Today is Thursday"'
What goes where `_____` is?

**Actual example**

```
<cfset aTable = "bookings">
<cfquery name="client" datasource="accounts">
    SELECT * FROM #aTable#
</cfquery>
```

What is the word the describes the way this is related to the statement

```
<cfset aTable = "bookings">
<cfquery name="client" datasource="accounts">
    SELECT * FROM bookings
</cfquery>
```

Would you say "after the value of the variable is substituted into its identifier"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `"Today is " + Weekday` **evaluates to** `"Today is Thursday"`

Answer (score 2):

If the substitution is done automatically by recognizing variable references inside a string, a common term is "interpolation".

If you perform the substitution using an explicit operator like "+" in Javascript or "." in Perl or PHP, it's called "concatenation".